# proving existence of Lebesgue measure on $((0,1], \mathcal B(0,1])$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Source: Probability with Martingale by Williams Page 200-201. Target: self study.
As the last step of the proof why is proving $\mu_0(H_n) \downarrow 0$ same as proving that for $\varepsilon>0$, $\mu_0(H_n)\geq 2 \epsilon, \forall n$, then $\bigcap\limits_k H_k \neq \emptyset$?

Further in the proof, For each $k \in \mathbf N$, we can choose $J_k \in \Sigma_0$ such that, with $\overline{J}_k$ denoting the closure of $J_k$, $\overline{J}_k \subseteq H_k$ and $\mu_0(H_k\backslash J_k)\leq \varepsilon 2^{-k}$. Why can we write $\mu_0(H_n \backslash \bigcap\limits_{k\leq n}J_k)\leq \mu_0(\bigcup\limits_{k\leq n}(H_k\backslash J_k))$?

Answer (score 1):

$H_n \backslash \bigcap\limits_{k\leq n}J_k\subseteq \bigcup\limits_{k\leq n}(H_k\backslash J_k)$ because $H_n$'s are decreasing: Let $x \in H_n \backslash \bigcap\limits_{k\leq n}J_k$. Then $x \in H_n \subseteq H_k$ and $x \notin J_k$ for some $k$ so $x \in H_k\setminus J_k$.